# Order email confirmation

Tags: email, order-email, magento-1.4, order-confirmation

I am using SMTP pro extension for managing emails.

Customer email confirmation was working fine previously, although no configuration was changed, i am having issue with order email confirmation. Test email is working fine with SMTP pro extension but email is not sent upon placing order.

In log exception, i get exception error: exception 'Zend_Mail_Exception' with message 'Subject set twice' in /xyz.com/lib/Zend/Mail.php:721.

I am working on the version 1.4.x, so i don't think there is cron issue with this version in order confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Is your cron running? Magento 1.9's order emails are placed in a queue that gets processed via a Magento cronjob.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, the version i am working now is in 1.4.1

Comment: Wow.. you should upgrade

Comment: yup, i am migrating the site to 1.9.x in local, but the client had issue in the live site which is in 1.4

Comment: Upgrading will probably fix it..

Answer (score 0):

So happens to be the client set the Authentication to none in SMTP email tab in configuration > Advanced > System.

Selecting the authentication to login now and email confirmation is sent.